# Ubuntu 11.04 Eclipse Java not running

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am new to java programming, Ubuntu, and Eclipse (usually work on win7 ultraedit/monodevelop/visualstudios with C#, C++, MONO, PHP)

I have installed the java-sdk ( + tons of other java packages ) on my machine + Eclipse and cannot run a simple project through Eclipse.

I can build a .java file, by executing the java file in the terminal using javac to build the class file and java file.class to execute it. I want to use eclipse to build and run my project and it's not working.

In my eclipse run configurations I have it using the JRE java-6-sun-1.6.0.26 (which is installed) but it's still not working.

When I try and run a simple project

```
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){ }
    }

}
```

the only thing in the console is:

```
main(1)[Java Application] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java (Sep 20, 2011 12:22:12 PM)
```

That path and file does exist. I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your main method.  This will run for ever without doing anything.

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true){
        System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
    }
}
```

and run again.

Comment: THANK YOU!!, I was expecting a command prompt to pop up or something.

Comment: You may want to restart Eclipse to get rid of any old running programs.

Comment: @Patrick Eclipse has a console view, in which the output of your program will be visible. No separate command prompt or shell window will open when you run your app from inside Eclipse. Note that this is the same as when running Eclipse on Windows; this has nothing to do with using Ubuntu.

Comment: You can close any old running apps by clicking the cross in the top-right corner of the console.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your default java settings:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

IIRC, Eclipse in Ubuntu depends on OpenJDK.

You can set up your default jvm by running:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```